# htaccess Re-writing URL with redirect causes loop

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have an existing site with php in the URL indexed. I want to change the URLs to not include PHP so thepage.php will be rewritten to http://example.com/thepage

The rewrite is working, but the redirect causes a 'page can't be displayed in a loop' error when I try to access the page as using thepage.php

I need to figure out how to setup the redirect and also rewrite the URLs, because Google has now indexed the PHP URLs and the pretty URLs.

I've looked at countless pages online, but can't find the answer.

Please help.

Here's my htaccess

```
# The redirect below caused a loop when I access the page as 
# http://example.com/thepage.php
# Moving the redirect after the rewrite didn't work either. 

Redirect 301 /thepage.php http://example.com/thepage

RewriteEngine on
# Rewrite works. The page does display corectly for this link
#    http://example.com/thepage

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
   Options +FollowSymLinks 
   Options +Indexes 
 #  RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d 
#RewriteRule ^photos([^\.]+)$ photos [NC,L]
   RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L] 
</IfModule>


ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite rule is backward from the sounds of it.

Here we're capturing all php files that do no contain periods and redirecting them to a directory URI using only the name without the extension. `[R=301]` is a permanent 301 redirect that tells whoever that the page is no longer in its old place.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+).php$ $1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

You might want to test these with `R` only without the 301 to make sure it's working. If you do a 301 redirect that doesn't work it will be cached in the end user's browser cache until it expires.

Apache has an [extensive reference on remapping URLs with redirects](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html).

Comment: Thank You. When I do this I get 404 error for all pages except the home page

 RewriteEngine on

 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    Options +FollowSymLinks 
    Options +Indexes 
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d 
   RewriteRule ^([^\.]+).php$ $1 [NC,L,R=301]
 </IfModule>


 #ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to get back to this problem and found the solution. I hope this can help somebody else. I tore my hair out on this problem.

I found many examples but not with the combination that I needed

```
#Force non-www:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteBase /

# hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+).php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

# To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/
```